# Finding the limit for fractions..

Tags: limits

Find the limit: $$\lim_{x \to -{6}} \frac{(1/6)+(1/x)}{6+x}$$

Comment: If you let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then this can be written as:$$\lim_{x\to-6} \frac{g(x)-g(-6)}{x-(-6)}$$ So the value is $g'(-6)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\dfrac16+\dfrac1x}{6+x}=\frac{6+x}{(6+x)6x}=\frac1{6x}$$ if $x+6\ne0$

If $x\to-6,x\ne-6$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\require{cancel}
\lim_{x\to-6}\frac{\cfrac{1}{6}+\cfrac{1}{x}}{6+x}=\lim_{x\to-6}\frac{\cancel{(x+6)}}{6x\cancel{(x+6)}}=\lim_{x\to-6}\frac1{6x}=-\frac{1}{36}.
\end{equation}